# Tremulous install on Bionic Beaver

Tags: software-installation, games

I've got a new laptop with Ubuntu Bionic Beaver. I'd like to install Tremulous to play with, but the installer fails, and I can't find any package for my system.

```
bash tremulous-1.1.0-installer.x86.run 
 Verifying archive integrity... All good.
 Uncompressing Tremulous 
 1.1.0.......................................................................................... .....................................................................
 ./setup.sh: 201: ./setup.sh: /home/#####/.setup2976: not found
 The setup program seems to have failed on amd64/unknown
 
 Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
```

How can I install this game?

Comment: Where did you get the installer?

Comment: This is the original installer on tremulous.org.